# After installing Ubuntu 21.04, programs can't write to NAS

Tags: permissions, mount, 21.04

I've had a couple of programs copying or moving files from my Ubuntu PC to my NAS - FreeFileSync for backups and a custom Python script for maintaining my media library.  Since upgrading to 21.04 both have reported errors:

- FreeFileSync reports errors on files it tries to sync in the form of:

  `"Cannot write modification time of "/mnt/backup/Google Drive/DocumentsBackup/temp.a086.ffs_tmp". Error Code 1: Operation not permitted [futimens]"`
- The Python script outputs an error which prevents the move from completing (the file appears to be copied but without the modified time, which seems suspicious given the above error):

  `"error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted"`
- If I copy files manually, there appears to be no error but the modification time is also not retained which suggests the same underlying issue, just without an error dialog.

If I run the Python script using `sudo` it successfully completes with no errors, which makes it smell like a permissions handling change in 21.04?

The shares are mounted using the following `/etc/stab/`, working prior to the upgrade:

```
//192.168.7.32/video /mnt/videos cifs username=guest,password=<...>,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0 0 0
//192.168.7.32/homes/Backup2015 /mnt/backup cifs username=guest,password=<...>,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0 0 0
```

I've tried adding `gid=1000,forceuid,forcegid` to the above definitions in case it improved matters with no luck.